# Gantt charts in Redmine -increase column size of issue description?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins, gantt-chart

Is there a way to increase the column size of the issue description in Gantt chart in Redmine?Are there any backend files that need to be edited? Or any patches that need to be applied?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.A new plugin is available in [Git]:https://github.com/kulesa/redmine_better_gantt_chart
 for a better gantt.We can not customize the chart.But it will improve the gantt performance.